# Is there a shortcut to create only right angles while editing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, arcgis-pro, perpendicular

While digitizing in ArcGIS Pro, I am wondering if there is a way while creating segments to allow only right angles. I understand that this can be done manually by entering direction, deflection, or perpendicular (as well as keyboard shortcuts for those). I want to know if there is a quicker way to achieve this.

Ideally, I would like to have a key-binding that I could hold down while drawing line or polygon segments; it would constrain the next segment to be placed at a perpendicular offset (90 or -90).

I am digitizing a large number of buildings in a city (automatic extraction options not available). It would be too time-consuming to manually enter deflection angles throughout the whole process.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: [Creating a segment at a right angle (90 degrees) to the previous segment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-a-segment-at-a-right-angle-90-degrees-.htm)

Comment: With QGIS this can be done with the Advanced Digitizing Panel (formerly CAD tools) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsjmLa16obs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the drop down beside the trace tool in your Editor toolbar and selecting the right angle option as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I feel kind of silly now for not realizing that was there. I suppose I should have included in my question that I am working in ArcGIS Pro at the moment. But that is what I was looking for! I just need to figure out if there is a way to change the editor toolbar.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with ArcGIS Pro, I found a link that seems to explain how to accomplish right angles with your application.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-features-with-right-angles.htm

Comment: Also - You can switch between editing tools while drawing in a feature.  So if you're building isn't completely square corners, you can switch to the appropriate tool to draw one or two segments, then go back to right angles to finish it up.  Also helpful is the "Square and Finish" option on the right-click menu - that works nicely for the final corner on a building.