# Adjusting angles after drawing polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, editing, angles

[image]

I need to adjust the angles of a polygon that I've drawn in the ArcMap environment.
In fact, I've converted the polyline to polygon by using data management tools and features. Now I want to modify the angles of the new polygon to 90 degrees exactly. I did not find the deflection tool in this mode.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193360/276

Comment: The above link is suitable when we want to draw a new polygon. But I have had it right now and would like to adjust its angles to 90 degrees.

Comment: I think you will need to create a temporary shape. If you create a polygon (or possibly just a graphic) using the rectangle tool, you can use it as a guide to adjust your vertices, even moving it around like a T-square. It is way easier to just use the rectangle tool at the outset, if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is the angles will not be necessarily exactly 90 degrees after doing this process.